# How does the TypeScript NPM package register itself as tsc?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to make a package that has one or more aliases. I am aware that you can install aliases during the `npm i` command, but I am curious as to how TypeScript is doing it.

When I run `npm i typescript -g`, I can execute `tsc` afterwards. How is this alias made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you globally installed Typescript, the executable creates a symlink for you.
You can view all installed packages `npm -g --list` .

```
/usr/local/bin/tsc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
/usr/local/bin/tsserver -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
```

`npm i <pkg_name>` installs a package into your project. I don't believe it installs aliases. Packages are install in your project's `node_modules` folder.

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to set up a script executable from the command line like: `npm run myalias`.

Alternatively, you can add aliases to your command line: `alias rm='rm -i'`

Comment: How can I make my own package make a symlink on install? The `alias` command won't work on Windows for instance, so I'm still curious as to how they've done it in a cross-platform manner.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. It's the `bin` part of a `package.json` file that controls it.